# Why isnt this returning the new string?

Tags: java, string, recursive-query

I have a recursive method that reversed a string (HW assignment, has to be recursive). I did it....but its only returning the value of the string after the first pass. By analyzing the output after each pass i can see it does do its job correctly. heres my code, and the output i get below it:

```
    String s = "Hello, I love you wont you tell me your name?";
int k=0;
public String reverseThisString(String s) {
    if(k!=s.length()) {
        String first =s.substring(0,k)+s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        String end = ""+s.substring(k, s.length()-1);
        k++;
        s=first+end;
        System.out.println(s);
        this.reverseThisString(s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

output:

```
?Hello, I love you wont you tell me your name
```

Comment: is it a homework, since it's difficult to reverse a string this bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change this:

```
this.reverseThisString(s);
```

to this:

```
return this.reverseThisString(s);
```

otherwise the result of the method call is simply discarded.

I would also recommed that you change k to be a parameter to the method rather than a member.

Comment: and mark beat me to the punch while I was re-tagging. so instead of posting i'll just say - what he said

Comment: @bestsss: It seems like he has made a reasonable effort to do the work himself, IMHO. It's not just 'give me the codez' - he has an almost working solution.

Comment: @mark, keeping a member variable as counter is quite a bad idea

Comment: Get rid of the `this`, it's just meaningless clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mark said, you forgot the return statement.

Also, there is an easier way to reverse a string (which is my current homework too :P )

`public String reverse(String s) {

    if(s.length() <= 1)

        return s;

    return reverse(s.substring(1))+s.charAt(0);

}`